# How to split the columns of a dataframe by their name?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe df:

```
a.1 b.2  c.33 ...
1   kuku 3
44  bubu 441
55  wewe 4441
```

I want to split the column to be `a 1 b 2 c 33` like this:

```
a   1  b    2
1   1  kuku kuku 
44  44 bubu bubu 
55  55 wewe wewe .....
```

How can this be done, please advise?

Comment: Please provide what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with:

```
mydf <- structure(list(a.1 = c(1L, 44L, 55L), b.2 = c("kuku", "bubu", 
    "wewe"), c.33 = c(3L, 441L, 4441L)), .Names = c("a.1", "b.2", 
    "c.33"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Use a combination of `rep` and `strsplit` (for the names):

```
setNames(data.frame(rep(mydf, each = 2)), 
         unlist(strsplit(names(mydf), ".", TRUE)))
##    a  1    b    2    c   33
## 1  1  1 kuku kuku    3    3
## 2 44 44 bubu bubu  441  441
## 3 55 55 wewe wewe 4441 4441
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain what row.names = c(NA, 3L) does?

Comment: @Dr.RichardTennen, The dataset actually doesn't have rownames, so it's just being given an integer sequence from 1 to the number of rows in the dataset. This information is usually shown when you `dput` your dataset to make it easy for others to reproduce.